# Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope' - when trying to use socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, socket.io

i have a react app in the client side,
and express js in the server side.
the i cant connect to socket.io server.

in the client side i trying to connect socket.io connection inside the useEffect:

```
            const socketio = io(server, {
                query: {
                    userid: user.admin ? `admin` : user._id,
                },
            });
            setSocket(socketio);
```

and in the server side i starting the socket.io server like this:

```
const http = require("http");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

.......all server's code

server.listen(3002);
```

when i running the system locally on my pc, all works fine.
when i uploading this to the hosting service, it giving me this error in the console:

```
POST https://***.com/socket.io/?userid=64d159ddf4e0fa2126411be1&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OdO_OCY&sid=80U0tfEmLLxWf5jYAACQ 400

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used.
    at sw.js:38:16
```